# How to work with imports correctly in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror

I have the follow project structure

```
- app
  - folder1
    - folder2
      - __init__.py
      - classA.py
    - folder3
      - __init__.py
      - classB.py
    - tests
      - __init__.py
      - test_classA.py
      - test_classB.py
```

classB.py

```py
from folder2.classA import clsA
```

I running tests the follow command and it works

```
cd app\folder1
python -m unittest discover
```

aslo if in Pycharm I add the folder1 in source, and run classB.py it works, but in vsCode when I running classB.py I get an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'
```

how to add folder1 in vscode to source as in pycharm?

also I tried

```py
from ..folder2.classA import clsA
```

and got

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I trying to fix it a second day, but nothing work in vscode works only in pycharm

Comment: A longer read but totally worth it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ".." in vscode. It cannot be recognized.

You can use absolute paths. And add it into sys.path by using method sys.path.append().

You could refer to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044366/python-package-import-works-in-spyder-but-not-vs-code) what I answered before.