# How to use "../" in VS CODE to acces a folder outside the current folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to access a folder outside my current folder, however when I Use "../images/image.png" it gives a FileNotFound error. Now running this code in IDLE gives no error and works perfectly. How can i use ../ in Vs code?

Using `pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load(f"./images/ui/logo.png"))` which gives :- `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.` running it in **IDLE 3.9, doesnt give me any error**

Comment: Almost certainly because the current working directory in VSCode is not what you think it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: using `pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load(f"./images/ui/logo.png"))` which gives :- `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory`. running it in IDLE 3.9 doesnt give me any error @BoarGules

Comment: I realize that. I suggest you do `print(os.getcwd))` in each of the two environments, at the point where you are trying to open the file, and compare what they say. If they are not the same then `..` means different things.

Comment: They Are different! running `getcwd()` in IDLE gives :- `C:\Users\name\Desktop\Programs\Python\PyGames\test\rewrite\code`
while in vs code:-
`C:\Users\name\Desktop\Programs` @BoarGules

Comment: There really wasn't any other explanation for the behaviour you reported. As I said, it was almost certainly because the current working directory in VSCode was not what you thought it was. A reason to avoid relative paths where possible. Much better to make file locations a configuration setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that if the code in vscode involves paths, everything is retrieved for the root directory based on the workspace. Even if you use "." in a deep directory under the workspace, this still represents the workspace directory, instead of the current directory.

So what we need to do is to change our thinking and import the files you want with the workspace as the root directory.

This also means that ".." will not appear in vscode. Because all the files we need are in the workspace, we will not use the parent directory outside the workspace.

For example,

> "./images/ui/logo.png"

[image]

If you place it like this, you can retrieve the file anywhere in the workspace without complex positioning based on the current file.

You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044366/python-package-import-works-in-spyder-but-not-vs-code). It has similar problems with you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that both folders are in the same directory. This means that you should use “./“ instead of “../“ :)

Comment: Hey, i tried it but it didnt work
im using `pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load(f"./images/ui/logo.png"))`
which gives :- `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.`
running it in IDLE 3.9 doesnt give me any error

Comment: I think you have no good reason to make that assumption. And OP wants a file *outside* the `cwd`, not *in* it.